# Tesseract recognizing Arabic text in android

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract, arabic, tess-two

I'm developing an application which I use Tesseract OCR to recognize a text in an image. I tested it for English and Japanese and it works fine, but when I tried Arabic the application crashes before even launching! Why?

What's wrong with the Arabic language and Tesseract OCR? Can someone tell me please?

**Code:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Bitmap image;
private TessBaseAPI mTess;
String datapath = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init image
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_ara);

    //initialize Tesseract API
    String language = "ra";
    datapath = getFilesDir()+ "/tesseract/";
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();

    checkFile(new File(datapath + "tessdata/"));

    mTess.init(datapath, language);
}

public void processImage(View view){
    String OCRresult = null;
    mTess.setImage(image);
    OCRresult = mTess.getUTF8Text();
    TextView OCRTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OCRTextView);
    OCRTextView.setText(OCRresult);
}

private void checkFile(File dir) {
    if (!dir.exists()&& dir.mkdirs()){
            copyFiles();
    }
    if(dir.exists()) {
        String datafilepath = datapath+ "/tessdata/ara.traineddata";
        File datafile = new File(datafilepath);

        if (!datafile.exists()) {
            copyFiles();
        }
    }
}

private void copyFiles() {
    try {
        String filepath = datapath + "/tessdata/ara.traineddata";
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream instream = assetManager.open("tessdata/ara.traineddata");
        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = instream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outstream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }


        outstream.flush();
        outstream.close();
        instream.close();

        File file = new File(filepath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**The error I got:**

```
   04-16 18:37:08.451 7405-7405/com.imperialsoupgmail.tesseractexample A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 7405 (esseractexample)
```

Comment: Post the exact error text when it crashes.

Comment: @sashoalm just posted it.

Comment: @LamaTatwany I try your code but it is also not working for English can you please guide me and share trained data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Arabic, you need to use Cube: call [init()](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/3debecf75af3a5d54f566f42a1a07d729852b01c/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java#L299) using the `OEM_CUBE_ONLY` engine mode and use the Cube [data files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#cube-data-files-for-version-304305).

Comment: I just posted the code, can you please tell me where should I change and how? or are there any good examples of how to use the Cube?

Comment: thanks! now it works :) but the recognition is wrong! do you know why?

Comment: I can't say without more information. Ask a new question and include all the details.

Comment: Also try `OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED`.

Comment: when I tried OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED, the application will fail to launch!

Comment: Rmtheis and @LamaTatwany did you find a solution ? please I can't find cubes files and I don't know where can I set OEM_CUBE_ONLY in the code ?